# how can we import contact from lost mobile to new mobile

Tags: contacts, recovery-mode

i lost my samsung android mobile, now i bought a new samsung android. Let me know how to get recovery of contacts in my new mobile.

Answer (score 3):

If you had auto-synced  your device with your Gmail, you would probably have the backup of all the contacts. So, You can login with the same account as that of the lost phone and then retrieve the contacts from gmail/gdrive backup.

Comment: google account was there but unfortunately its not synced. So please share any other way to get it

Comment: You cannot recover stuff only saved locally without access to that location. If the device is lost, so is its content, sorry @jithender.